# Has the suffix "-trix" acquired a pejorative meaning in recent years?

Tags: word-usage, connotation, pejorative-language, suffixes, political-correctness

A couple days ago I needed the correct word for a female aviator, which I figured was *aviatress*. A [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aviatress?s=t) search provided *aviatress*, *aviatrice* and *aviatrix* as acceptable choices. Coincidentally, I had just read this EL&U [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100083/what-is-the-origin-of-ix-as-a-feminine-variation) about the origin of the -trix suffix, and so I explored other Latin-based agent nouns. I found that *legislatress* exists along side *legislatrix* as does *benefactress* with *benefactrix* and *orator* with *oratress*. Not so with *dominatrix*, though. It seems to have maintained only the -trix suffix.

Dictionary.com has [this](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-trix) to say about the -trix suffix in modern use:

> Most nouns in -trix  have dropped from general use, so that terms like aviatrix, benefactrix, legislatrix, oratrix,  and proprietrix  occur rarely or not at all in present-day English.

Dominatrix has maintained, and most people would only ever use it in the realms of sado-masochism and sexual role play.

My question is, why has the -trix suffix fallen off and been replaced by the more sibilant "-tress"? And, have we avoided the -trix suffix to avoid any unintended association with the sado-masochistic sense of dominatrix?

Comment: I wouldn't understand a word with this suffix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's just that the *-or* suffix isn't generally thought of as implying gender today (in the movie industry we increasingly see references to [female actors](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22female%20actors%22&oq=%22female%20actors%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.6313&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), for example).

Effectively, there's a general tendency towards either switching to existing gender-neutral terms, or forcing the main (invariably male) form to be treated that way.

I'd also say the *-trix* suffix isn't really "productive" today. If we really want that distinction, we'd probably use *-ess* (in which context I'll just note the [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/protectrix) definition *protectrix = protectress*)

I wouldn't give much credence to the idea that we avoid *-trix* because of associations with the only significant survivor *dominatrix*. I think we avoid the form because it's dated/archaic - but in that one particular case it's been retained because it's a very specialised context where issues of "gender equality" don't really arise. Nobody complains about the "sexist language" of [Miss whiplash](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22female%20actors%22&oq=%22female%20actors%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.6313&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Miss%20whiplash%22&oq=%22Miss%20whiplash%22&gs_l=serp.3..0l4.998878.1002520.0.1003390.13.13.0.0.0.0.127.709.12j1.13.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.eYEN0pZGaQ4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=e9fe9caeb27ca466&biw=1253&bih=886) either!

Comment: Also note [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=proprietrix%2Cproprietress&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) showing the comparative irrelevance of *proprietrix* as against the "standard form" *proprietress*.

Comment: This was my wife's argument, too: that modern post-feminist English is doing away with feminine suffixes; and I agree. But some feminine suffixes remain where gender is non-essential (enchantress, sorceress, hostess). As well, I can't imagine calling someone a dominatrix if only to refer to her dominating qualities and not her leather bustier and handcuffs.

Comment: @tylerharms: Quite so. Next time I use one of those ["dial a dominatrix"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22dial+a+dominatrix%22&oq=%22dial+a+dominatrix%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.9843955&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) services, I shall certainly demand a refund if Ms Whiplash arrives without all the expected paraphernalia!

Answer (score 11):

The college I attended (several decades ago) had, instead of a "student body president," an "executor" or "executrix," depending on the gender of the officeholder. A quick Google search yields 9420 matches for *executress* and 1.26 million matches for *executrix*, suggesting that *executrix* remains the more common feminine form of *executor*.

I don't know whether the *-trix* ending has fallen into particular disfavor, nor whether, if so, that disfavor is due in any way to the influence of *dominatrix*. I do think that, in general, adding feminine endings to occupations that normally lack them (as with *comedienne* or *poetess* or *aviatrix*) strikes a discordant note in modern usage because such a word choice may seem to imply that the person's performance of an objectively gender-neutral role is inseparable in some way from her being female. Why should a woman with expertise in grammar be labeled a *grammarienne*?

The main exception to this tendency involves the term *actress*, which seems to carry no invidious or patronizing overtones; other words such as *heiress* may also qualify as exceptions.

---

**Update (October 4, 2020): *A reference work's discussions of '-ess' and '-trix'***

Michael Quinion, *Ologies and Isms: A Dictionary of Word Beginning and Endings* (Oxford: 2002) has the following entries for *-ess* and *-trix*:

> **-ess** *Forming nouns denoting the female gender.* {From French *-esse*, via late Latin from Greek *-issa*.} Many examples exist: ***actress***, ***countess***, ***duchess***, ***enchantress***, ***hostess***, ***lioness***, ***ogress***, ***peeress***, ***poetess***, ***princess***, ***waitress***. In some cases it can mean 'wife of': ***ambassadress***, ***mayoress***. Such forms are now often seen as sexist or patronizing; many have been replaced to a greater or lesser extent by the stem term, taken to be neutral in gender (*poets*, for example, may be either male or female). Some examples  are now mainly of historical or poetic relevance, such as ***abbess***, ***goddess***, ***priestess***, and ***shepherdess***.
>
> ...
>
> **-trix** Also **-trice**. *Forming feminine agent nouns.* {Latin suffix corresponding to masculine *-tor*.} Though many words with this suffix have been created since  the 15th century, few have been common; those few that do appear mostly now do so only in formal legal contexts: ***executrix*** (the female equivalent of *executor*), ***administratrix*** (of *administrator*), and ***testatrix*** (of *testator*). One that has come back into use in the latter part of the 20th century after a long fallow period is ***dominatrix***, a dominating woman who takes the sadistic role in sadomasochistic sexual activities. Other examples, now only historical, are ***aviatrix***, a female *aviator*; ***editrix***, a female *editor*; and ***proprietrix***, a female *proprietor*. The spelling **-trice** an alternative form, via French, now almost totally archaic. The plural of words ending in **-trix** is either *-trices* or *-trixes*.

On the *-trice* front, I note that *cockatrice* (a mythical snakelike monster with a deadly gaze) may or may not involve a feminized cock. Here is the entry for *cockatrice* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **cockatrice** *n* {ME *cocatrice*, fr. MF *cocatris* ichneumon, cockatrice, fr. ML *cocatric-*, *cocatrix* ichneumon} (14c) : a legendary serpent that is hatched by a reptile from a cock's egg and that has a deadly glance.

The "legendary serpent" meaning of *cockatrice* seems to have originated in Middle French, not Middle Latin. The notion that the creature emerges from a "cock's egg" brooded by a reptile adds a gender-bending—if not explicitly feminine—element to the term. An ichneumon, however, is neither a bird nor a reptile but a mongoose, which, of course, is a snake-eating member of the weasel family (and not anserine in the least).

Comment: Even actress, though, is becoming dated. As this [Link](http://www.cjr.org/language_corner/womens_suffixes.php?page=all&print=true) suggests.

Comment: should "adimistratrix" above be "administratrix" ???

Comment: @BenBolker: Yes, it should. Thank you for pointing out the typo!

Answer (score 2):

There is another pejorative influence; *meretrix*, meaning 'prostitute' in Latin, is the root of *meretricious*, meaning 'second-rate', and there are various quotations about 'the meretrix with her merry tricks'.  I wouldn't say it was an important influence, but presumably it might make some people avoid the *-trix* suffix.